# How to solve some hardcore Recurrences?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I am trying to solve these Recurrences for my algorithms class. Can someone please help me because Master Theorem does not work and I can not compute the sum that occurs from the tree in the first and I have not seen a good solved example for the second!

T(n) = 2*T(n/3) + n/log^2(n)

T(n) = T(n-10) + logn

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem, [cs.se] or [math.se] may be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I am new and I did not know about these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example is a job for Master Theorem: `a=2, b=3, f=n/log^2(n)`. `log_b(a) < 1`, so it is the third case, because f(n) grows (significantly) faster than `n^(log_b(a))*log^k(n)` for any k. This means that main job is done outside recursion and `T(n)=O(n/log^2(n))`.

Second example can be solved this way:

```
T(n)
= T(n - 10) + log(n)
= ...
= log(n) + log(n - 10) + ...
= log(n * (n-10) * (n-20) * ...)
= [n = 10k]
= log(10^k) + log(k!)
= k*log(10) + k*log(k) - k + O(log(k))
= O(k*log(k))
= O(n*log(n))
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that in the first case there was a non-polynomial difference between f(n) and n^{log_b a} because of the log^2(n), but now I get that this is not the case.

Comment: @Saraki Trick is, there exists degree d (say, d=0.9), so that d>log_3(2) and n^d=o(f(n)). So to speak, n^(log_b(a)) and f(n) are "divided" by n^d.